# Arrows and buttons vanished in IIS7 / Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

[Cross-posted on http://datatables.net]

Hi,
can anyone offer me clues about this problem?

I have a web site running on IIS6 and Windows Server 2003. It uses an add-on for JQuery UI called "datatables" (http://datatables.net). In the DataTables objects, it displays the up-and-down arrows in the sortable column headings, and "prev / next" button at the bottom-right of the table.

If I copy the entire site to a server with IIS7.0 and Windows Server 2008, the arrows and the buttons no longer appear. I can still sort the columns by clicking on their headings, and navigate to the previous and next pages by clicking on the words "prev" and "next". However the graphic arrows and buttons do not appear.

I did find a reference to this kind of problem; http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6353/arrow-next-to-the-header-of-the-table-is-missing/p1
However, that suggests the cause is a missing .css file and in my case, I know none is missing.

I have upgraded DataTables from v1.8 to v1.9.1, and ensured that the application pool in IIS7 is "classic", supposedly compatible with IIS6, but the arrows and buttons did not re-appear.

All suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: Did you check browser console? if it can't find/download a fail you'll be noticed. Moreover check how it did resolve the span style (and you'll see if something in the css is omitted).

Answer (score 0):

In IIS7, if I remember correctly you need to enable static content, which is not selected by default. I remember that when I first used IIS7 that was my main problem. There are more details about it here: http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/05/23/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation.aspx